# How to move several text files to several listed directories?

Tags: file, batch-file

I have this code to move several listed text files to several listed directories.

```
set /P "from=from: "
set /P "to=to: "
for /L %%a in (%from%,1,%to%) do move %%a.txt %%a^\file.txt
echo Done..
pause;>nul
```

The files below

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
```

are moved into the directories below

```
\1
\2
\3 
\4
\5
```

by moving every file to the directory with same name and change the name of the text file to default `file.txt` by executing the commands:

```
move 1.txt 1\file.txt
move 2.txt 2\file.txt
move 3.txt 3\file.txt
move 4.txt 4\file.txt
move 5.txt 5\file.txt
```

But I need to update my code to move several text files as listed below

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
```

to several listed directories as listed below of which names are stored in a text file with name `listed_directories.txt`

```
768643
234893
9890f8
uk573d
kiodk3
```

I want a code which result in executing the commands:

```
move 1.txt 768643\file.txt
move 2.txt 234893\file.txt
move 3.txt 9890f8\file.txt
move 4.txt uk573d\file.txt
move 5.txt kiodk3\file.txt
```

I stopped here with:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color 0a
set /P "from=from: "
set /P "to=to: "
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%N IN (listed_directories.txt) DO set R=%%N & for /L %%a in (%from%,1,%to%) do move %%a.txt %%N\file.txt
echo Done..
pause;>nul
```

Has somebody an idea how to code the batch file to get the desired file movements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that these code lines is what are you looking for:

> @ECHO OFF
>   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>   set /P "STARTNUMBER=From: "
>   set /P "ENDNUMBER=To: "
>   set NAMEFILE=%STARTNUMBER%
>
> FOR /F "delims=¶" %%N IN (listed_directories.txt) DO (
>
> move !NAMEFILE!.txt %%N\file.txt
>
> if !NAMEFILE! EQU %ENDNUMBER% (echo Done) else (
>   set /a NAMEFILE=!NAMEFILE!+1
>   )
>   )
>
> pause > nul

This short script allows you to obtain what is in your last example. Your attempt to get this result - I mean the `for` cycle inside another `for` cycle - yields a properly recursive task and, theoretically (I have not tested it), the result is:

> move 1.txt 768643\file.txt
> [...]
> move 5.txt 768643\file.txt
> move 1.txt
>   234893\file.txt
> [...]
> move 5.txt 234893\file.txt
> etc.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set /P "from=from: "
set /P "to=to: "
for /L %%a in (%from%,1,%to%) do IF EXIST %%a.txt (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%r IN ('findstr /n /r "." q25216106.txt') DO (
  IF %%r==%%a ECHO(move %%a.txt "%%s\file.txt"
 )
)
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

This should move
 `1.txt` to the directory given in the first line **\file.txt**
 `2.txt` to the directory given in the second line**\file.txt**
and so on, but only for the lines in the range you specify as input.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

I used a file named `q25216106.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply..
the second answer work great..thank you again sir...